# Angular change displayed value

Tags: html, angular, forms, input

I have an input that retrieve a numeric value. I would like to change the display on the html side, basically if the variable equals to let s say 7 the value displayed becomes 'abcdefg' instead of 7. On the contrary if I type abcdefg I would like for the form to understand that the value that should be stored is 7 and not the string. Is there a way to do that only on the HTML side ?

```
<div class="col-6">
 <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Cardinality Max" required #asbiepCardinalityMax
  (change)="changeMax(asbiepCardinalityMax.value)"
  (focus)="focusInMax(asbiepCardinalityMax.value)"
  [(ngModel)]="asAsbiepDetail().cardinalityMax" 
  (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
  [disabled]="!isEditable() || !asAsbiepDetail().used"
  (keypress)="numberOnly($event)">
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Do you want to show the length of your string?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor  ?

Comment: I have a form which contains a specific input. This input returns a numeric value. I want to allow a string value instead of the numeric value. Basically all numbers will be displayed as they are except for 7 that I want to be displayed as 'abc'. Obviously if I type abc the value I wanna store is 7 and not abc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to separate out the logic for controller to view binding and view to controller. You want to add separate functions for updating and reading. You can either add an event handler to set the value onChange and remove the () from the ngModel (removing the view -> controller updating), or use typescript getters and setters to bind to one value, with different logic.

Option 1:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-6">
 <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Cardinality Max" required #asbiepCardinalityMax
  (change)="changeMax(asbiepCardinalityMax.value)"
  (focus)="focusInMax(asbiepCardinalityMax.value)"
  [ngModel]="fieldValue()" 
  (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
  (change)="setFieldValue($event)"
  [disabled]="!isEditable() || !asAsbiepDetail().used"
  (keypress)="numberOnly($event)">
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@Component({})
export class Controller {
  realValue: number = 7;

  setFieldValue($event) {
    let newValue = $event.target.value;
    //Code here to turn newValue into something correct for real value
    if (newValue == 'abcdefg') {
      realValue = 7;
    }
  }

  fieldValue(): string {
    if (realValue === 7) {
      return 'abcdefg';
    }
  };
}
```

Option 2:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-6">
 <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Cardinality Max" required #asbiepCardinalityMax
  (change)="changeMax(asbiepCardinalityMax.value)"
  (focus)="focusInMax(asbiepCardinalityMax.value)"
  [(ngModel)]="fieldValue" 
  (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
  [disabled]="!isEditable() || !asAsbiepDetail().used"
  (keypress)="numberOnly($event)">
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@Component({})
export class Controller {
  realValue: number = 7;

  set FieldValue(newValue): void {
    //Code here to turn newValue into something correct for real value
    if (newValue == 'abcdefg') {
      realValue = 7;
    }
  }

  get fieldValue(): string {
    if (realValue === 7) {
      return 'abcdefg';
    }
  };
}
```

And then you use realValue where you want.

The advantage of the first is you can pick what event you want to fire the function that sets the value on the controller - you might want change, keyup, keydown, blur - you can have any of the classic javascript events. The second approach requires onChange.